# To remove special characters like <p>, <li>

Tags: php

I want to display content on client side. The problem is that I am getting output like this -

```
<p> Aliette is a systemic fungicide effective against Oomcytes fungi like downy mildew
diseases of grapes and damping off and Azhukal diseases of cardamom.</p> <span> Despite
its extensive use since 1978, there is no report of resistance development in fungus. 
True systemic action makes application of Aliette as the best prophylactic solution for 
downy mildew control in grape.</span>
```

Now I want to remove those special characters i.e `<p>`,`</p>`, `<span>`, `</span>`

Value stored in database is description = "<p> test <p>";

```
$sel_pro = "select * from bayer_product where product_group like '%".$_REQUEST['searchfield']."%'";
$res_pro = mysql_query($sel_pro);
$num_pro = mysql_num_rows($res_pro);
while($row_pro = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_pro))
{
        echo $desc = strip_tags($row_pro['description']);
}
```

Comment: I have added special characters but it is not visible here. For eg- Content is displayed like this <p> sfsfsf</p>. I want to make invisible <p>, </p>

Comment: @jassi now it is :) fixed that for ya

Comment: Do you mind adding your code?

Comment: @Aleks G -  I wont mind adding my code. and moreover I am not clear with what you had asked?

Comment: he means show us what you've tried. But as you've already a valid and correct answer from @sgt, it may be worth [accepting that as the answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) by pressing the tick under the score to the left.

Comment: @hd - I know it is a right answer but the point is that my problem didnot get solved. I have fetched content from database and now displaying it in client side. In database it is stored in this format <p>dfdfsdf</p>.Code is - $desc = strip_tags($row_pro['description']);                                <span><?php echo $desc; ?></span>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they are tags then you can use [`strip_tags()`.](http://php.net/strip_tags)

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

the outputs will be

```
Test paragraph. Other text //strip all tags
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a> //strip all tags except <p> & <a>
```

Comment: it is not striping the tags?

Comment: No, it is not striping the tags. I am fetching content from database. It is stored in this format <p>ewrewr</p>

Comment: I have edited the question. You can have a look the way I have implemented. value of description is "<p>test</p>";

Comment: `$row_pro['description']` contains the text then it should return the correct value ??

Comment: Yes that is true but dont know why it is displaying with special characters. Since it is working on other pages.

Comment: Really sorry, Actually in database the value is stored in this format $description = "&lt;p&gt;
   Aliette is a systemic fungicide effect... &lt;p&gt;"

Comment: the right answer is  echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode(stripslashes($desc),ENT_NOQUOTES,"Utf-8"));

Comment: the answer is given according to your question. @jassi

Comment: Yes, I am really sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

For clean all html tags in text use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) function. Usage you can see in the docs. If you need to clean all tags, except few that you need - simply put "allowable_tags" param.
http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.strip-tags.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP function strip_tags for remove tag

```
<?php
$text = '<p> Aliette is a systemic fungicide effective against Oomcytes fungi like downy mildew
diseases of grapes and damping off and Azhukal diseases of cardamom.</p> <span> Despite
its extensive use since 1978, there is no report of resistance development in fungus. 
True systemic action makes application of Aliette as the best prophylactic solution for 
downy mildew control in grape.</span>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Autorise <p> et <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><span>');
?>
```